# Shiny stuff on Eric's head

Tags: character, true-blood

There's some shiny stuff attached to [Eric Northman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_Northman)'s head in Season 2 (Episode 1 and 2) of True Blood. It looks metallic, and I would like to know what it is and what it's for.

[image]

Above is an early scene from Episode 2, just after a bloody exercise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think Eric is getting his hair dyed (aluminum foil is a common item used in bleaching or coloring hair).

I can't quite remember the reason he did this - but one suspects he was looking to change his appearance for some reason.

There is circumstantial evidence in [this post](http://www.screened.com/eric-northman/15-1634/all-images/132-1977849/0000006/131-490771/) and in this [YouTube clip](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h8fGPfGFNKY), he's clearly wearing something to protect his clothes from the dye too.